# C# Check if a method exists in TDD

Tags: c#, unit-testing

In Java I can check if a method named "addNumbers" exists in a class "Calculate" by doing this:

```java
Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.example.package.Calculate");
Method m = c.getMethod("addNumbers", int.class, int.class);
m.invoke(5,7)
```

What is the C# equivalent for this example?

Comment: Erm, why not just call this method from your test? That way you'll get a compile-time error if the method doesn't exist, and you also get the chance to test what the method *does*

Comment: I can't understand why you'd need to do this in a statically typed language (which both Java and C# are).

Comment: Because I want to test if the pupils implemented the method "addNumbers" from the exercise task. It works in java, so I assume there must be a c# equivalent for this approach.

Comment: It's called "reflection".

Comment: Though you can do it by reflection, there are cleaner ways to enforce implementing a method. Why don't you just let the pupils implement an `ICalculator` interface with an `AddNumbers` method?